# Kernel and image of linear operator $\alpha(f) = f(t+1) - f(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory

> Let $V = K[t]_n = \{f \in K[t], \deg f \le n\}$. Find kernel and image of the operator $\alpha(f) = f(t+1) - f(t)$.

My attempt: I can take a standard basis $1, t, \cdots, t^n$ and find matrix of the linear operator:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 0&  \binom{1}{0}&  \binom{2}{0}&  .& \binom{n}{0} \\ 
 0&  0&  \binom{2}{1}&  .& \binom{n}{1}\\ 
 .&  .&  0&  .&. \\ 
 .&  .&  .&  .&\binom{n}{n - 1} \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&0 
\end{bmatrix}$

So, if $\text{char}K = 0$, then $\text{rank } A = \dim\text{Im } \alpha = n$ (it is $K[t]_{n - 1}$), and $\ker \alpha = K[t]_0 = K$

But I don't know how to solve it if $\text{char} K\ne 0$ ($K$ is a field)

Comment: A small example to show that the answer indeed changes: with $K = \Bbb F_2$ and $n = 2$, the image consists only of constant polynomials.

Comment: For $\text{char}K = p > 0,$ the rank and the nullity of $A$ are $n-\lfloor n/p\rfloor$ and $1+\lfloor n/p\rfloor.$  This can be seen by Gauss-Jordan elimination.  However, it doesn't seem to give you a way to write what the image and kernel actually look like, other than basic statements about the degrees.

Comment: One can prove with induction that $\alpha(f)(0)=\alpha(f)(1)=\alpha(f)(2)=\ldots$. So if $\operatorname{char} K = p>0$ and $n\le p$, then the kernel consists of only the constant polynomials.